# Can I customize JAXB @XmlElementWrapper elements for a java.util.Map

Tags: mapping, jaxb, jaxb2

I'm trying to learn to use Map with Jaxb.
I did this:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "phoneNumbers", nillable = true)
private Map<String, PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
```

and the result was:

```
 <xs:element nillable="true" name="phoneNumbers">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="key" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="value" minOccurs="0" type="PhoneNumberType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Is there any way to change the "entry","key","value"  element names?

I've tried to use @XmlElements, @XmlElement but I just got errors.

Comment: also check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718112/xsd-to-java-specify-to-use-a-java-hashmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use an XmlAdapter if you want finer control over the XML representation of a Map property.  For more details see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

I have entered an enhancement request to handle this in the MOXy JAXB implementation:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/322423