# JAXB to be create a map from XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

When JAXB generates this, it create the OtherProperties as a List. How can I configure the XSD so it is generated as a Map?

```
            <xsd:element name="OtherProperties" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:element name="Property">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:string" />
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the following question:

- [Can I customize JAXB @XmlElementWrapper elements for a java.util.Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448702/can-i-customize-jaxb-xmlelementwrapper-elements-for-a-java-util-map/3449268#3449268)

Standard JAXB has limited support for handling java.util.Map.

To get the xml representation you want you will need to use an XmlAdapter:

- [XmlAdapter - JAXB's Secret Weapon](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html)

Are you interested in this direction?